# How can configuration tools like sdl-config be used with a cabalized project?

Tags: haskell, sdl, cabal

I have a working SDL/Haskell application that I would like to build using Cabal instead of the current Makefile (because that is the "Haskell way"). The Makefile is itself very simple, and I was hoping that the default cabal build process could allow me to reconstruct a build command specified in my Makefile. The problem is that it makes use of "sdl-config", a utility that gives you all the necessary cc- compiler options:

```
wrapper.o: SDLWrapper_stub.h
    ghc -no-hs-main `sdl-config --cflags` -Wall wrapper.c -c
```

Cabal does not seem to expand that into a shell call when calling GHC. How can I specify that sdl-config's options should be fed into GHC when compiling `wrapper.o`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the `configure` style in Cabal, you can write a little configure script that substitutes a variable for the output of the sdl-config command. The values will then be replaced in a $foo.buildinfo.in file, yielding a $foo.buildinfo file, that Cabal will include in the build process.

*General solution: the configure script*

```
 #!/bin/sh

 SDLFLAGS=`sdl-config --cflags`
 echo Found "$SDLFLAGS"
 sed 's,@SDLFLAGS@,'"$SDLFLAGS"',' z.buildinfo.in > z.buildinfo
```

*The $foo.builinfo.in file*

```
cc-options: @SDLFLAGS@
```

*The .cabal file*

```
Build-type:          Configure
```

When you run "cabal configure" the "cc-options" field in z.buildinfo will be created to hold:

```
cc-options: -I/usr/include/SDL -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT
```

which cabal will include in the build.

Done.

*Specific solution for pkg-config tools*

For tools that support the [*pkg-config*-style](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config) of configuration, such as `sdl` or `cairo` and others, Cabal has specific support already:

> **pkgconfig-depends: package list**
>
> A list of pkg-config packages, needed to build this package. They can be annotated with versions, e.g. gtk+-2.0 >= 2.10, cairo >= 1.0. If no version constraint is specified, any version is assumed to be acceptable. Cabal uses pkg-config to find if the packages are available on the system and to find the extra compilation and linker options needed to use the packages.
>
> If you need to bind to a C library that supports pkg-config (use pkg-config --list-all to find out if it is supported) then it is much preferable to use this field rather than hard code options into the other fields.

So for `sdl` you just need:

```
pkgconfig-depends: sdl
```

Comment: Hey. I followed your instruction and Mikhail's in editing the .cabal file; when I try to build I get something like:

cabal: internal error: the package contains a library but there is no corresponding configuration data

But my project does not contain a library. It contains only one executable. What could this message possibly mean?? :/

Comment: Check the syntax of your .cabal file (or try generating a new one with `cabal init`). Back up your old .cabal file first though.

Comment: No luck. Same message.
In fact, the original file was generated with `cabal init`, and I have changed very few things.

I filed this one as a cabal bug on Hackage trac. I think it's clear enough to me that the message isn't really describing the problem adequately.

Comment: Well I've tracked down that the `z.buildinfo` file above didn't declare a executable <<binary-name>> section, which probably made cabal think it was a top level (library) field when the `.buildinfo` file merged with the `.cabal` file.

I think I've figured out another neater way to do it: cabal has a `pkgconfig-depends` field, in which I simply say `sdl`. However, I need to figure out how to compile the necessary code stubs for FFI now...

Comment: Oh, yes, the `pkgconfig-depends` that libs like GTK use! That's *much* better.

Comment: Cheers for the help Don. Everything seemed to go alright until I ran into the dreaded libiconv problem on OS X... and of course that's a well known issue with potential solutions of which I have all tried but have not yet solved :(
Strange that I never had to link with libiconv before using cabal; the Makefile compiled things happily. I'll keep you posted :P

Answer (score 3):

Use the `Configure` build type in your `$PROJ_NAME.cabal` file and generate a `$PROJ_NAME.buidinfo` file from a `$PROJ_NAME.buildinfo.in` template with a `configure` script. Look at the source of the [SDL](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/SDL) library on Hackage for an example. [This section](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html#system-dependent-parameters) of the Cabal user guide provides more details.

One tip: do not forget to mention `$PROJ_NAME.buildinfo.in` and `configure` in the `extra-source-files` field.